# VBA data parser changing text values

Tags: vba, copy, text-parsing

I found this useful hunk of code online but I am running into a problem where excel is incorrectly copying the text from the files. The script parses the data from a text file and adds it to a new sheet for every text file. Sometimes the values are returned correctly but sometimes they are not. For example, if the text is "00000E8F" it parses it correctly but if it is "00000E02" it reads this as scientific notation and therefore sets the value to 0. Is there a way to force the script to copy the text as a "text" datatype?

```
Sub Test()
'Script is meant for .txt files with 4 columns seperated with tabs
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xToBook As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt")
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
            xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
            Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            CSB_File_Interpretation
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            xWb.Close False
        Next
    End If
    Summary
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Range("Copy")` and on a new line `Range("Destination").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`?

Comment: This may work. The single line copy/paste method pastes everything (values, format, etc). If you switch to the multi line copy/paste you can specify what should be pasted. In this case, you strictly want values

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by formating the cells to type "text" and then reading individual lines from the text file. Then I just cycled through a For loop until the end of the text file. I'm still curious if there is a way to do it with the method I was previously trying.